# Odin Axe using Selenium : Database (SQL) support

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I am evaluating `Odin Axe automation tool` for my new project using `Selenium` as underlying test tool. Now, my question is Selenium doesn't support database connectivity on its own. When I developed my testing framework using selenium only, I used `Hibernate` to check SQL verification and validation. But, now that I am using `AXE`, I don;t know how to check database verification for a particular test script.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: There's JDBC. I don't know why you would resort to something like Hibernate for test automation, that seems overkill.

Comment: @SiKing - thanks for comment. But, does Odin AXE support JDBC?

Comment: I never heard of Odin AXE, but your post is tagged with [tag:java], and that certainly does support JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axe doesn't use Selenium on its own. It builds a program that drives Selenium. Depending on what you choose it can be java, csharp or even ruby. You'll need to create a custom method to get the data and an action in action map to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Axe is supplied with a component called AxeHarness which is used to test at the component level. It currently supports SOAP Web Services, database and .NET APIs. If you look at the HarnessDemo sample project that is provided with Axe then you can see how this could be employed to perform database queries to validate your tests.

Of course you can also easily role your own database validation, as mentioned in the answer provided by Rad.